# Remap kmeans labels_ based on sorted cluster_centers_

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm using KMeans to cluster records in a data set based off of one column, `cards`, which is an int. However, the cluster labels returned are in an non-intuitive order (which is expected since it's an unsupervised algorithm).

To make the output more intelligible for my colleagues, I would like to remap the labels to the order of the `cluster_centers_`.

I created a DataFrame where `index` is the KMeans generated label, `set_size` is the intended new label (having been sorted on the `min` column), but I'm stuck on the last leg of the puzzle.

How do I remap the `cluster_df['set_size']` values to `all_sets_df['set_size']` where `all_sets_df['cluster'] == cluster_df['index']`?

I've tried variations on apply, lambda, map, using a dict, but for some reason I get np.nan in 2/3 of the results (if it works at all). I feel like this is really obvious, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

```
# Assign optimal clusters to all_sets_df.set_size column

print('Assigning sets to clusters...', end='')
X = all_sets_df.cards.reshape(-1, 1)

n_clusters = 3

km = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, init='k-means++', n_init=10)

all_sets_df['cluster'] = km.fit_predict(X)

cluster_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {_i: {'set_size': _i, 
          'min': all_sets_df.cards[all_sets_df.cluster == _i].min(), 
          'max': all_sets_df.cards[all_sets_df.cluster == _i].max()}
    for _i in range(n_clusters)}, 
    orient='index').sort_values(by='min').reset_index()

cluster_df['set_size'] = range(len(cluster_df.set_size))

print('done.\n')

print(cluster_df.ix[:, ['index', 'set_size', 'min', 'max']].to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
Assigning sets to clusters...done.

index  set_size  min  max
    2         0    1  100
    0         1  113  230
    1         2  244  449
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tried `_f = lambda x: cluster_df['set_size'][cluster_df.index == x].values
all_sets_df['set_size'] = all_sets_df['cluster'].map(_f)` but it returned the same cluster labels as I started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change the line

`_f = lambda x: cluster_df['set_size'][cluster_df.index == x].values`

to

`_f = lambda x: cluster_df['set_size'][cluster_df['index'] == x].values[0]`

as it was using the actual dataframe index which was identical to the cluster label when mapping values from the cluster_df table. Also, the values returned by the lambda function were lists of length 1, so `[0]` needed to be added to the end of the function.

Here is the final code block that ended up working for me.

```
_f = lambda x: cluster_df['set_size'][cluster_df['index'] == x].values[0]
all_sets_df['set_size'] = all_sets_df['cluster'].map(_f)
all_sets_df = all_sets_df.drop('cluster', axis=1)
```